# Remove unwanted / invalid attributes from html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html node which has invalid characters in the attributes (basically corrupted attributes) like below.

`<p data-test="123" "="">bla bla</p>`

It has invalid character ("="") in the attribute. How can this be removed programmatically?

```html
<p help="123" "="">bla bla</p>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove this programmatically? Such as, if you type an invalid character, JavaScript removes it for you? Or are you asking how to get around this error so that you can use the equal sign?

Comment: I would not use JavaScript to fix such issues. I would fix those issues at the source. Not at the delta. Also, besides the `"=""` mess, `help="123"` is not a valid HTML5 attribute... so there's lots to fix over there.

Comment: Yes, exactly. @ConnorLx3. $(element).removeAttr('"') is not helping.

Comment: how is the server outputting it? maybe u need escaping to solve the problem

Comment: @Surya It's not working because you are trying it with JQuery, try it with pure javascript like on my answer

Comment: @Surya use JS, not jQuery: `myEl.removeAttribute('"')` is helping. If you then do: `console.log(myEl.outerHTML)` you'll get `<p help="123">bla bla</p>` - anyways. Don't use JS at all. Go fix that issue on the backend side - or wherever.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `$('p').removeAttr('"');` works fine. jQuery isn't the issue.

Comment: @N.Tasikj jQuery isn't the issue at all.

Comment: @Unmitigated depends on which browser did u tried
The .removeAttr() method uses the JavaScript removeAttribute() function, but it has the advantage of being able to be called directly on a jQuery object and it accounts for *different attribute naming across browsers*.

Comment: @N.Tasikj The whole point of jQuery is for cross-browser compatibility. It's not going to change attributes that aren't standard in some way.

Comment: @Unmitigated what I meant (but did not wrote) is that a library is not necessary for such a simple task. Actually no JS should be used at all. The issue should be ideally fixed on the origin.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Indeed, I agree the issue should not be fixed at this level.

Answer (score -1):

To remove that attribute with Javascript you need to select an element and call `removeAttribute()` on it

```
selector.removeAttribute('"')
```

Your selector can be like this:

```
document.querySelector('p[help="123"]').removeAttribute('"')
```